# Pandas value_counts on multiple columns : inconsistent result (bug ?)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe :

```
   df = pd.DataFrame( np.array([
       [ 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [ 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1],
       [-1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1] ] ) ,
        columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"])
```

and I want to compute the number of time each row sequence of values appears (an histogram of the rows). For this I use `value_counts` :

```
df.value_counts()
```

But I got the following output with missing values for some sequences and some of the beginning columns :

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
 1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  1    3
     1   1  -1   1   1  1    1
                -1  -1  1    1
-1  -1  -1   1   1   1  1    1
            -1   1   1  1    1
dtype: int64
```

After looking at the data, it seems that when a value is identical in the first columns, it is not always output.
Is this a bug ? How can I get an histogram with full row values ?

I'm using Python 3.7.9 with pandas 1.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `value_counts()` is a series, with a MultiIndex representing the values.

```
df.value_counts().index.values
#array([(1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1), (-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1),
#       (-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1),
#       (1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1)], dtype=object)
```

Try this to see if formatted better if you're in a Jupyter notebook:

```
newdf = df.value_counts().to_frame("counts")
```

or

```
newdf2 = df.value_counts().to_frame("counts").reset_index()

print(newdf2)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  counts
0  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1       3
1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1       1
2 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1       1
3  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1       1
4  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1       1
```

If you want a simple bar chart, you can do:

```
newdf.plot.bar()
```

[image]